# Design Broadband Matching Networks for Amplifier Mathworks Example

Tags: matlab, radio

Does someone have full code for this example :

https://ch.mathworks.com/help/rf/ug/designing-broadband-matching-networks-part-2-amplifier.html

I get Error:

> File: hw.m Line:  10 Column: 36 The expression to the left of the
> equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

And also when I try to load example like this:

> openExample('rf/DesigningBroadbandMatchingNetworksPart2AmplifierExample')

I get this error:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>
> Error in openExample>readMetadata (line 95) metadata.component =
> tokens{1};
>
> Error in openExample (line 10) metadata = readMetadata(id);
>
> Error in Untitled2 (line 5)
>
> openExample('rf/DesigningBroadbandMatchingNetworksPart2AmplifierExample')